# How to find the stationary points

Tags: partial-derivative

Find the stationary points: $$f(x,y)=x^2-\frac 13y^3-xy$$

Have so far with respect for $x$: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x-y$

With respect for $y$: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-y^2-x$

But having trouble getting from here?

Answer (score 1):

The stationary points are the solutions of the two equations:
$$2x-y=0$$
$$-y^2-x=0$$

that is

$$y=2x$$
and 
$$-4x^2-x=0$$

i.e.,  $x=0$ or $x=-1/4$

That is, the stationary points are $(0,0)$ and $(-1/4,-1/2)$